# String Assignment to variable is still nil

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, nsstring

So I'm using AWS Cognito to authenticate my users from my iOS application. However in a small bit of code, I've narrowed down an extremely odd problem while making some minor changes.

I noticed that I was receiving this error:

> Unable to refresh. Error is [Error
>   Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderErrorDomain Code=1
>   "identityId shouldn't be nil"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=identityId shouldn't be nil}]

After debugging, I've noticed the identityId actually does not get set:

```
_identityId = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"IdentityId"];
self.keychain[EncryptionKeyKey] = self.identityId;
return [AWSTask taskWithResult:nil];
```

Though I clearly set it in the above code block, and checked to make sure that [jsonDict objectForKey:@"IdentityId"] did produce some value, I found through the debugger that a "po self.identityId" before and after the assignment is still nil. NSString isn't something that needs to be allocated, and what's weirder is that this used to work. I switched some statements up because of my current use of UICkeychainstore but that shouldn't affect anything. In addition, I disposed of my changes and saw that the problem still exists. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

I'm also noticing this error shortly after the previous error:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

any ideas would be very helpful

Comment: Please show that you have in jsonDict dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had both a login method and a getToken method. In the getToken method I wasn't doing something right based on some changes I had made to the code to use keychain instead of nsuserdefaults for security reasons. After fixing the getToken it worked. After further debugging though, I saw that identityId still doesn't get set regardless of it working or not. I guess it might be some sort of block variable s.t. the assignment doesn't happen immediately. At least that's my theory. All in all it works though.